# Append URL Fragment to URL When A Bootstrap 4 list-group panel Parent Item Is Clicked

Tags: bootstrap-4

When a bootstrap 4 `<a href="node##" ...></a>` references an HTML `id` for the purpose of expanding a a vertical accordion-style expand/collapse sidebar, how do I force the address bar to append the URL fragment of the `list-group-item` node?

For example, If I click the "Gardening" list-group-item, it expands showing the items under it but I also want to simultaneously put the `#node11` into the current URL.

[image: not expanded menu]

**Desired Result**

If the current page was http://www.example.com/home/. when I click the "Gardening" menu item, the menu expands and the URL changes to http://www.example.com/home/#node11. Then, if I click the "Lawn Chemicals" menu item, the URL changes to http://www.example.com/home/#node13. So the URL gets the node ID appended and/or updated when a `list-group-item` item is clicked that has children.

[image: expanded]

Reproducible example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-nowrap">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="list-group panel">
          <a href="#node11" class="list-group-item level-0" data-parent="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse"
             aria-expanded="true">Gardening <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <div class="collapse show" id="node11" style="">
            <a href="#node13" class="list-group-item level-1" data-parent="#node13" data-toggle="collapse">Lawn
              Chemicals <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="collapse" id="node13">
              <a href="gardening/lawn-chemicals/moss-control/" class="list-group-item level-2" data-parent="#node13">
                Moss Control</a>
            </div>
            <a href="gardening/lawn-mowing/" class="list-group-item level-1" data-parent="#node11">Lawn Mowing</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Why I'm confused about this:

The `<a href="">` either reference an HTML ID or an actual URL. When they reference and HTML ID, I'm not sure how to make it also change the current URL.

Comment: Purely from the HTML perspective, it doesn't matter whether this refers to an actual id or not, it would always show the anchor in the address bar, if not actively prevented - and this is what bootstrap is apparently doing. I guess you could easily use [one of the events provided](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/list-group/#events) to set the location.hash yourself; not sure though whether that'll give you an actual connection to the browser history, if that is the desired effect, meaning that clicking the back button would also toggle back the current and previous items.

Comment: @CBroe you hit the nail on the head of what I'm trying to do - make a connection to the browser history when clicking back it would toggle back to the previously opened item in the tree. That's my entire intent of trying to put the `#node##` in the URL. But when I do this manually and hit back, it doesn't seem to work like that. I'll look into your events link your provided.

Comment: You’ll probably have to implement a hashChange handler for that, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange

Answer (score 0):

A solution I found was to use javascript like so:

```
<script>
    $('.list-group').on('click', '.list-group-item', function () {
        var clickedID = this.id;
        window.location.hash = clickedID;
        alert(clickedID);
    });
</script>
```

Full example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.0/css/all.css"
      integrity="sha384-lKuwvrZot6UHsBSfcMvOkWwlCMgc0TaWr+30HWe3a4ltaBwTZhyTEggF5tJv8tbt" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="text-nowrap">
      <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="list-group panel">
          <a href="#node11" class="list-group-item level-0" data-parent="#sidebar" data-toggle="collapse"
             aria-expanded="true" id="gardening">Gardening <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
          <div class="collapse" id="node11" style="">
            <a href="#node13" class="list-group-item level-1" data-parent="#node13" data-toggle="collapse"
            id="lawn-chemicals">Lawn Chemicals <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>
            <div class="collapse" id="node13">
              <a href="gardening/lawn-chemicals/moss-control/" class="list-group-item level-2" data-parent="#node13"
              id="moss-control">Moss Control</a>
            </div>
            <a href="gardening/lawn-mowing/" class="list-group-item level-1" data-parent="#node11"
            id="lawn-mowing">Lawn Mowing</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    $('.list-group').on('click', '.list-group-item', function () {
        var clickedID = this.id;
        window.location.hash = clickedID;
        alert(clickedID);
    });
</script>
```

**Take-away**: the javascript adds a URL fragment (a hash) to the URL when one of the link `list-group-item`s are clicked. In this case, I had to add a unique `id` to each `list-group-item` so I used a slug-like value.

**Next step** is to figure out will be how to open the accordion navigation to the element the user had last clicked if they for example hit back in their browser (so the user won't have to re-open the tree again). Not sure how to do this yet but this is where I'm at:

```
if(window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.slice(1);
    var elem = document.getElementById(hash);
    var node = elem.hash.slice(1);
    var x = document.getElementById(node);
    x.classList.add('show');
} else {
  // Fragment doesn't exist
}
```